# Creating fixed FCE with fluidcontent

Tags: fluid, fedext

Width this code i can define content:

```
 <flux:flexform.section name="columns">
    <flux:flexform.object name="column" label="column">
      <flux:flexform.field.input name="demo" label="Demo field" />          
    </flux:flexform.object>
  </flux:flexform.section>

  <flux:flexform.grid>
    <flux:flexform.grid.row>
      <f:for each="{columns}" as="sectionObject" iteration="iteration">
        <flux:flexform.grid.column>
          <flux:flexform.content name="column{iteration.cycle}" label="Column {iteration.cycle}" />
        </flux:flexform.grid.column>
      </f:for>
    </flux:flexform.grid.row>
   </flux:flexform.grid>
```

This is flexible. I can Add new "Content Areas" through the section. But this is not what I want. I Want to define a very fixed two-column and a three-column FCE. My editor should not have to decide how many columns to use.

I am missing something like:

```
 <flux:flexform.field.contentArea name="col1" label="Column 1" />           
 <flux:flexform.field.contentArea name="col2" label="Column 2" />           

  <flux:flexform.grid>
    <flux:flexform.grid.row>
        <flux:flexform.grid.column>
              <flux:flexform.content name="col1" />
        </flux:flexform.grid.column>
        <flux:flexform.grid.column>
              <flux:flexform.content name="col2" />
        </flux:flexform.grid.column>
    </flux:flexform.grid>
  </flux:flexform.grid.row>
```

Thank you for your hint to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the solution with the code you already have. In this example I will use the *new* ViewHelper names - but you can get the same result using the *old* names as in your example. Which is which, should be easy to spot (note: you had a typo in your code example which I edited, `rgid` used instead of `grid` - such a typo would cause Flux to error out):

`<flux:grid>
    <flux:grid.row>
        <flux:grid.column>
              <flux:content name="col1" label="Nice name for column 1" />
        </flux:grid.column>
        <flux:grid.column>
              <flux:content name="col2" label="Column 2" />
        </flux:grid.column>
    </flux:grid>
  </flux:grid.row>`

And remove the `flux:form.section` with object inside it - you don't need this when you make a statically defined grid.

Then to render this grid:

`<flux:content.render area="col1" />` and so on.